# What is the error in this Preference?

Tags: paypal, magento2.3.4, preference, override-model

Due to PayPal Error, i am updating the following function in `app/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php`, not edit the entire code just update a single function.
Function Name :  function _applyStreetAndRegionWorkarounds()

My Preference:

**app/code/Gta/PayPalPreference/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Gta_PayPalPreference',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Gta/PayPalPreference/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Gta_PayPalPreference" schema_version="0.0.1" setup_version="0.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Gta/PayPalPreference/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"
>
 <preference
     for="Magento\Paypal\Model\Api\Nvp"
     type="Gta\PayPalPreference\Model\Api\Nvp"
 />
</config>
```

**app/code/Gta/PayPalPreference/Model/Api/Nvp.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Gta\PayPalPreference\Model\Api;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Nvp extends \Magento\Paypal\Model\Api\Nvp
{
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address $customerAddress,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $customLogger,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        \Magento\Paypal\Model\Api\ProcessableExceptionFactory $processableExceptionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedExceptionFactory $frameworkExceptionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\CurlFactory $curlFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($customerAddress, $logger, $customLogger, $localeResolver, $regionFactory, $countryFactory, $processableExceptionFactory, $frameworkExceptionFactory, $curlFactory, $data);

        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    protected function _applyStreetAndRegionWorkarounds(DataObject $address)
    {
        // e.g. if you do not want to run the code on website id = 2
        if ($this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId() == 1) {
            parent::_applyStreetAndRegionWorkarounds($address);
            return;
        }

        if ($address->getData('street2') !== null) {
            $address->setStreet(implode("\n", [$address->getData('street'), $address->getData('street2')]));
            $address->unsetData('street2');
        }
        if ($address->getCountryId() && $address->getRegion()) {
            $regions = $this->_countryFactory->create()
                ->loadByCode($address->getCountryId())
                ->getRegionCollection()
                ->addRegionCodeOrNameFilter($address->getRegion())
                ->setPageSize(1);
            if ($regions->count()) {
                $regionItems = $regions->getItems();
                $region = array_shift($regionItems);
                $address->setRegionId($region->getId());
                $address->setExportedKeys(array_merge($address->getExportedKeys(), ['region_id']));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error during the compile command,

> Warning: Declaration of
> Gta\PayPalPreference\Model\Api\Nvp::_applyStreetAndRegionWorkarounds(Gta\PayPalPreference\Model\Api\DataObject
> $address) should be compatib
> le with Magento\Paypal\Model\Api\Nvp::_applyStreetAndRegionWorkarounds(Magento\Framework\DataObject
> $address) in /var/www/html/test/app/code/Gta/PayPalPreferenc
> e/Model/Api/Nvp.php on line 59

**Note: website filter included.**

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/Gta/PayPalPreference/Model/Api/Nvp.php**

```
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is with the type of `DataObject` you're passing in `_applyStreetAndRegionWorkarounds(...)`. Try adding `use Magento\Framework\DataObject;` on top of your file.

Comment: Fatal error:  Cannot use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface as StoreManagerInterface because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/test/app/code/Gta/PayPalPreference/Model/Api/Nvp.php on line 8

Comment: maybe you're adding `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` twice?

Comment: sorry to mkae silly mistake.

Comment: no worries. See if that solved your actual problem.

Comment: After enabling the module, if i try to add a product to the add-to-cart i am getting the following error,

Invalid block type: Magento\Paypal\Block\Express\InContext\Minicart\SmartButton

How to solve the error?

Comment: If you disable this module then it works fine?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115854/discussion-between-zus-and-abdul-samad-abbasi).